# YouTubeStandalonePlayer shows black screen after returning to activity from background

Tags: android-youtube-api

When using the standalone player activity from the youtube api (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), if the user backgrounds the app via the home button, then task switches back in to the app, the video will refuse to show however the audio will continue to play.

This happens in my own app, but also is apparent in the sample app's "Standalone Player" activity.

From a poke around in View Hierarchy, I can see that when returning form the background, there is an extra view which could be blocking the video from showing. See the below screenshot of the working standalone player on the right, and the result of backgrounding and foregrounding the app on the left.

[image: View Hierarchy]

Anyone got any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @gauravjain I don't think I did I'm afraid

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @Prateek218 Have you got any solution for this?